# Can't access swarm 8500 port from outside

Tags: json-rpc, swarm

I run local swarm node, so I can access it from localhost:8500. RPC request works fine locally.
But when I try to send requests to swarm rpc from another server, it is not accessible. I see port 8500 is only open locally.

Seems very strange. Are there any options to open it for the network?

Comment: how do you try to access it?

Comment: I have no rep to comment, so reply here:
I try to send request by RPC

Answer (score 0):

This should have been addressed by providing the `httpaddr` flag:

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/14475

Per default swarm runs on localhost only.